# Python TypeError: got multiple values for argument

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

**What I am trying to accomplish**

I am trying to set up a Flask RESTful webservice in my project.
I store all the data in my PostgreSQL database. In my project I use SQLAlchemy to create datamodels for my tables.

I created a few Abstract models to add specific properties to all my models.
See the code below.

**The issue**

I have a model which represent a system User (UserModel). When I want to create a new User I get the following error:

> TypeError: **__init__()** got multiple values for argument 'user_type'

What I do:

```
user = UserModel("user@test.com", "test", "user", UserType.admin)
```

I do not understand why it says that the argument 'user_type' is getting multiple values while I pass on 4 arguments.
The init function haves 5, including the self property.

I am suspecting the Abstract classes, but I am not sure. When I remove the user_type argument and property I get this error:

> TypeError: **__init__()** takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

---

**usermodel.py**

```
from core.enums.usertypes import UserType
from core.models.base.auditeddeletemodel import db, ForeignKey, AuditedDeletable
from core.models.addressmodel import AddressModel


class UserModel(AuditedDeletable):
    """A model which contains information about an User.

    Attributes:
        emailaddress (string): The emailaddress for the User.
        first_name (string): The first name of the User.
        last_name (string): The last name of the User.
        user_type (UserType): The type of the User (default: viewer).
    """
    __tablename__ = 'Users'

    emailaddress = db.Column(db.String(100))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    date_of_birth = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    gender = db.Column(db.String(1))
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(100))
    password_salt = db.Column(db.String(100))
    user_type_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    mobile_phone_number = db.Column(db.String(30))
    home_phone_number = db.Column(db.String(30))
    address_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('Addresses.id'))
    address = db.relationship('AddressModel', lazy='select', foreign_keys=[address_id])


    @classmethod
    def __init__(self, emailaddress, first_name, last_name, user_type=UserType.viewer):
        """Inits UserModel with emailaddress, first_name, last_name, user_type."""
        super(UserModel, self).__init__()
        self.emailaddress = emailaddress
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.user_type = user_type

    @property
    def user_type(self):
        """UserType: Defines the type of the User."""
        return UserType(self.user_type_id)

    @user_type.setter
    def user_type(self, new_user_type):
        if isinstance(new_user_type, UserType):
            self.user_type_id = new_user_type.value
```

**basemodel.py**

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
from sqlalchemy.schema import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr, declarative_base

from core.database.dbmanager import DBManager

db = DBManager.get_db_instance()

class Base(object):
    """A model which functions as a basic model for other models.

    Adds the id property to other models.
    """

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)


    def __init__(self):
        super(Base, self).__init__()


Base = declarative_base(cls=Base)
```

**auditedmodel.py**

```
from core.models.base.basemodel import db, postgresql, declared_attr, ForeignKey, datetime, Base

class Auditable(Base):
    """A model which functions as an auditable model for other models.

    Adds the created_by_id, created_by and creation_time properties to other models.
    """
    __abstract__ = True

    @declared_attr
    def created_by_id(cls):
        return db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('Users.id'), nullable=False)

    @declared_attr
    def created_by(cls):
        return db.relationship('UserModel', lazy='select', foreign_keys=[cls.created_by_id])

    @declared_attr
    def creation_time(cls):
        return db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.now())


    def __init__(self):
        super(Auditable, self).__init__()
```

**auditeddeletemodel.py**

```
from core.models.base.auditedmodel import db, postgresql, declared_attr, ForeignKey, Auditable

class AuditedDeletable(Auditable):
    """A model which functions as an auditeddeletable model for other models.

    Adds the is_deleted properties to other models.
    """
    __abstract__ = True

    @declared_attr
    def is_deleted(cls):
        return db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)


    def __init__(self):
        super(AuditedDeletable, self).__init__()
```

Comment: Why is the `__init__` decorated with `@classmethod`?

Comment: Also, I would expect that reassigning `Base` in `basemodel.py` would cause the `super()` in your `__init__` not to work.

Comment: Indeed, my mistake. removing the `@classmethod` from the `__init__` in the UserModel solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Might be due to conflicting issues with the property called user_type and in the constructor you're doing "self.user_type = user_type" which will override this

Comment: He also defined a setter, so doing self.user_type would call the setter property function.